# How to bind a DependencyProperty of a UserControl to a property in it's ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

The question is not about how to get the stuff working, it already does; it's about some strange behavior I'm experiencing, and I need to understand it. I have a `ResourceDictionary` that contains some styles, one of them got `TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}"` and `x:Key="UCStyle"`; that one is applied on multiple `UserControl`s in the project.
Some of these `UserControl`s got `string State` property in their ViewModel to be used to apply Visual States (through an external class, and an attached property, bound to the ViewModel in XAML). Till this point everything was perfect, then, I tried to add `DependencyProperty State` to the `UserControl`, and simply bind it to the state property in the ViewModel, my attempt was:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--ResourceDictionary Source="..."/-->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource UCStyle}">
            <Setter Property="State" Value="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Style>
    <DynamicResourceExtension ResourceKey="MyStyle" />
</UserControl.Style>
```

This worked perfectly at the runtime, but in the design-time, it always underline these lines
[image: 'MyUserControl' TargetType doesn't match type of element 'UserControl'.]

And shows an error says:

> 'MyUserControl' TargetType doesn't match type of element 'UserControl'.

And doesn't apply neither `UCStyle` nor `MyStyle` in the XAML Viewer in Visual Studio, and doesn't even draw the child `UserControl`s properly. I didn't expect the solution to run properly, but it did!

Now my questions are:

- Why does it show these errors in the design-time while it runs properly?
- How to get rid of these errors in the design-time? (I cleaned, and re-built the solution, and restarted Visual Studio, and none of these worked)
- What's the best practice to deal with `UserControl` Visual States in such situation in **MVVM**?
- What's the best practice to bind a DependencyProperty of a UserControl to a property in it's ViewModel in **MVVM**?

*I'm using Visual Studio 2012.*

Comment: It's a bit odd that you use `TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}"` but use `<UserControl>` Tag. Shouldn't the tag also be `<local:MyUserControl>` too? Since that's what the error message actually says/complains about

Comment: @Tseng if I did so, I would be inheriting `<local:MyUserControl>` from `<local:MyUserControl>`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wpf designer is nefarious for showing bogus errors at design time.  You can't do much but ignore them.

Visual states are a concern of the UI, and therefore should be contained within the UI.  MVVM ***does not*** mean no codebehind.  Use your codebehind for UI tasks, and put your business logic in your view models.

Your question suggests you're creating custom view models to hold view logic for your user controls.  Seriously, don't do that.  That'll get you in trouble down the road.  It interferes with how databinding is designed to work.

There is no "best practice" for binding user control elements to properties defined on its surface.  It depends.  Using a style to do this seems odd, however.  You can simply give the root of the UserControl an `x:Name="root"` and then use `ElementName=root` in your binding.

**An** example of binding within a UserControl to a property defined on the UserControl (taken from an old prototype)...

Here's a UserControl designed to add or delete a list of stuff.

- DependencyProperties defined on the UserControl
- Bindings within the UserControl that bind to these properties

I don't guarantee this works, but it will illustrate how it's done:

```
public partial class ItemsEditor : UserControl
{
    #region Items
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Items",
            typeof(IEnumerable<Item>),
            typeof(ItemsEditor),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Item>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion  
    #region AddItem
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AddItem",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ItemsEditor),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public ICommand AddItem
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(AddItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AddItemProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion          
    #region RemoveItem
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RemoveItem",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ItemsEditor),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public ICommand RemoveItem
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RemoveItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemoveItemProperty, value); }
    }        
    #endregion  
    public ItemsEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It just lists a bunch of things, you can add a new thing or delete a thing from the list.  Here's the bindings in xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="LolPrototype.ItemsEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:UCsAndICommands"
             x:Name="root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type t:Item}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{Binding RemoveItem, ElementName=root}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddItem, ElementName=root}">Add</Button>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=root}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Obviously, you can define DataTemplates outside the list in an ancestor's resources.  The point is to show how ElementName bindings can be used to bind against properties defined in the UserControl.

Comment: But where/how to make that 'root' binding for a `UserControl`?

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad `<UserControl class="whatevs" x:Name="root" ...`

Comment: Understood. Thank you!